# Simple Dice Probability Question

Tags: probability

This problem is throwing me off because it seems extremely simple, but the answer given is not what I get. The book has the answer as 5/36, but wouldn't it be 6/36 which would reduce to 1/6? Because you could have the combinations 4/6, 5/5, 5/6, 6/4, 6/5, 6/6 which is six total combinations out of the total 36 possible ones... Am I missing something, or is this a misprint?

> What  is  the probability of  rolling a   pair    of  dice    and getting a   sum of  10  or  more?

Comment: Confusing statement of the problem (just fixed as I was typing this). If $X$ is total on two fair dice, then $p(X=10)=3/36,/,P(X=11)=2/36,$ and $P(X=12) = 1/36,$ so $P(X \ge 10)=6/36.$

Comment: It is a misprint.

Answer (score 3):

It is a misprint. The answer is $\frac 16$ because the  cases are as you have given i.e. $(4,6),(5,5),(6,4),(5,6),(6,5),(6,6)$, and  these are six cases out of $36$, giving the probability of $ \frac 16$.

Answer (score 1):

The text book must be wrong then

[image]

6 Combinations (4,6), (5,5), (5,6), (6,4), (6,5), (6,6)